# Javascript rollover

Tags: javascript, rollover

I'm stuck with the following challenge:

- My table has a basic (static) alternating color scheme for even/odd rows, containing different options (class).
- In addition Javascript should provide for:

  1. a rollover effect to show which row is pointed at by the cursor (onmouseover, onmouseout)
  2. a specific color for the row which contains the option selected by a mouse click (onclick).

I came up with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
tr.moduleRow-odd {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR            : #FF0000;
}

tr.moduleRow-even {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR            : #00FF00;
}

.moduleRowOver-odd, .moduleRowOver-even {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR            : #D7E9F7;
}

.moduleRowSelected-even, .moduleRowSelected-odd {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR            : #0000FF; 
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var selected;

function selectRowEffect(object, buttonSelect) {
  if (!selected) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
      selected = document.getElementById('defaultSelected');
    } else {
      selected = document.all['defaultSelected'];
    }
  }

if (selected) {

if (selected.className == 'moduleRow-even' || selected.className == 'moduleRowSelected-even') {
selected.className = 'moduleRow-even';
object.className = 'moduleRowSelected-even';
}

if (selected.className == 'moduleRow-odd' || selected.className == 'moduleRowSelected-odd') {
selected.className = 'moduleRow-odd';
object.className = 'moduleRowSelected-odd';
}

}
//selected.className = 'moduleRow';
//object.className = 'moduleRowSelected';
selected = object;

// one button is not an array
  if (document.checkout_payment.payment[0]) {
    document.checkout_payment.payment[buttonSelect].checked=true;
  } else {
    document.checkout_payment.payment.checked=true;
  }
}

function rowOverEffect_1(object) {
  if (object.className == 'moduleRow-odd') object.className = 'moduleRowOver-odd';
}

function rowOverEffect_2(object) {
  if (object.className == 'moduleRow-even') object.className = 'moduleRowOver-even';
}

function rowOutEffect_1(object) {
  if (object.className == 'moduleRowOver-odd') object.className = 'moduleRow-odd';
}

function rowOutEffect_2(object) {
  if (object.className == 'moduleRowOver-even') object.className = 'moduleRow-even';
}

//--></script>

</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onmouseover="rowOverEffect_1(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect_1(this)" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0)">
   <td>Option 1 - Row-odd</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onmouseover="rowOverEffect_2(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect_2(this)" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1)">
  <td>Option 2 - Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 2" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

When testing, after clicking a few times on the options, I loose the alternating static background (odd/even rows get the same color) and part of the rollover.

Any help is much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Dennis

Comment: i suggest you leave the rollover effect to CSS. Simply add `:hover` to a selector to apply a rule only when the mouse if over the matched nodes. Use something like `tr:hover` as a selector to get your started

Comment: You can even apply color transitions to soften the effect.

Comment: and one more thing, if compatibility with old browsers isn't a problem, use `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)` instead of adding classes manually to each row :)

Comment: For a better view of the observed effect, copy the last two rows of the table (and rename to Option 3 and 4) and add to the bottom of the table.

Comment: your problem is with the selectRowEffect. basically what you are doing is that if the selected row is even you are making the clicked one even... and same thing for odd so what happens is that your first selection determines the classes for the following clicks. if you selected an odd one first, all the following clicks will make rows odd and so on..

Comment: i also noticed that you are not using the `buttonSelect` parameter, update your function to use that parameter instead of the selected row's class and you should get it working properly :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your selectRowEffect function in order to fix your logic problem

As you can see, you only need to check if the selected row is even or not and revert its class to what i should be (unselect it).

And then, you can change the clicked row's class to the corresponding selected one. Note that i used the `? :` ternary operator which basically tests for the condition before the `?` and if it is true returns the part between `?` and `:` otherwise it returns the part after the `:`. The returned value is then affected to the object's className.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVwhZ/) to quickly see it in action.

```
function selectRowEffect(object, buttonSelect) {
    if (!selected) {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            selected = document.getElementById('defaultSelected');
        } else {
            selected = document.all['defaultSelected'];
        }
    }

    if (selected) {
        if (selected.className == 'moduleRowSelected-even') {
            selected.className = 'moduleRow-even';
        }

        if (selected.className == 'moduleRowSelected-odd') {
            selected.className = 'moduleRow-odd';
        }
    }

    object.className = buttonSelect == 1 ? "moduleRowSelected-even" : "moduleRowSelected-odd";

    selected = object;

    // one button is not an array
    if (document.checkout_payment.payment[0]) {
        document.checkout_payment.payment[buttonSelect].checked=true;
    } else {
        document.checkout_payment.payment.checked=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ABSOLUTELY GREAT! Works perfectly. I've added the `:hover` like you suggested. Thank you very much. Regards, Dennis

Comment: Hi Dany. Sorry to ask you again, but I cheered a bit to early. I have added two extra rows to the table (Option 3 and 4). The color scheme is unchanged (odd rows=red, even rows=green). When I first click on Option 2 and subsequently on Option 3, the second row (=even) turns red (=odd, instead of green). Clicking on Option 4 next turns both row 1 and 2 red. Do you have a fix for this (because I plan to expand the table later on). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem described is my last comment should read: I have added two extra rows to the table (Option 3 and 4). The color scheme is unchanged (odd rows=red, even rows=green). When I click on Option 1 up to 4 and subsequently go back up to Option 3, the fourth row (=even) turns red (=odd, instead of green). Do you have a fix for this (because I plan to expand the table later on)? Thanks in advance. Kind regards, Dennis.

Comment: `<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0)">
   <td>Option 1 Row-odd</td>
   <td><input type="radio" value="option 1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1)">
  <td>Option 2 Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" value="option 2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 2)">
  <td>Option 3 Row-odd</td>
  <td><input type="radio" value="option 3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 3)">
  <td>Option 4 Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" value="option 4" /></td>
</tr>`

Comment: ok take a look at the selectRowEffect(this, XX) basically the 2nd parameter should alternate between 0 and 1. The code that i posted earlier checks if you are passing 0 or 1 and this is what determines if the row is odd or even when deselecting it

Comment: You're right, the test turns out fine now. Thanks. I just need to check if the XX parameter alternates between 0 and 1 in the HTML generated by my .php file or that it ups by 1 each time an additional row is added (which I expect it does). I'll let you know. Thanks again for all the help so far.

Comment: Unfortuntely, the XX parameter ups by one with every additional row. Would it be possible to replace the `buttonSelect == 1` part by a check if the value is an even or odd number?

Comment: I added `function isEven(value) {
 if (value%2 == 0)
  return true;
 else
  return false;
}` and replaced `buttonSelect == 1` by `isEven(buttonSelect) == false`. All is well now it seems ...

Answer (score 0):

I put the full code snippet below for others to use. All credit goes to Dany Khalife, who put me on the right track.

Remember to adjust the javascript to reflect your own:
- file name (in my case: **rollover_test**)
- input field's name (in my case: **payment**)

```
<html>
 <head>
<style type="text/css">
tr.moduleRow-odd {
   BACKGROUND-COLOR            : #FF0000;
}

tr.moduleRow-even {
   BACKGROUND-COLOR            : #00FF00;
}

tr.moduleRow-odd:hover, tr.moduleRow-even:hover {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR            : #FFFF00;
}

.moduleRowSelected-odd, .moduleRowSelected-even {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR            : #0000FF; 
}
</style>
 </head>

 <body>
<script>
 var selected;

 function isEven(value) {
    if (value%2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function selectRowEffect(object, buttonSelect) {
    if (!selected) {
       if (document.getElementById) {
           selected = document.getElementById('defaultSelected');
       } else {
           selected = document.all['defaultSelected'];
       }
   }

   if (selected) {
       if (selected.className == 'moduleRowSelected-even') {
           selected.className = 'moduleRow-even';
       }

       if (selected.className == 'moduleRowSelected-odd') {
           selected.className = 'moduleRow-odd';
       }
   }

   object.className = isEven(buttonSelect) == false ? "moduleRowSelected-even" : "moduleRowSelected-odd";

   selected = object;

   // one button is not an array
   if (document.rollover_test.payment[0]) {
       document.rollover_test.payment[buttonSelect].checked=true;
   } else {
       document.rollover_test.checked=true;
    }
}
</script>

<table>
<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0)">
   <td>Option 1 - Row-odd</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1)">
  <td>Option 2 - Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 2)">
  <td>Option 3 - Row-odd</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 3)">
  <td>Option 4 - Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 4)">
  <td>Option 5 - Row-odd</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 5)">
  <td>Option 6 - Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 6" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note:
The script works just as well when you alternate for XX between 0 and 1 in **selectRowEffect(this, XX)**
, like this:

```
<table>
<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0)">
   <td>Option 1 - Row-odd</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1)">
  <td>Option 2 - Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0)">
  <td>Option 3 - Row-odd</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1)">
  <td>Option 4 - Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-odd" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 0)">
  <td>Option 5 - Row-odd</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="moduleRow-even" onclick="selectRowEffect(this, 1)">
  <td>Option 6 - Row-even</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="payment" value="option 6" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```